# ¿Cómo podría sumar los valores que corresponden al mismo mes?

Tags: python

Tengo este código y lo que hace es que suma los valores que corresponden al mismo mes.

```
lista_a = ['1/01/22', '2/01/22', '1/02/22', '2/02/22']
lista_b = [50, 60, 70, 80]
Lista_resultado = []

ultimo_mes = lista_a[0][2:4]
suma = 0
indice = 0
while(indice < len(lista_a)):
    mes_actual = lista_a[indice][2:4]

    if(ultimo_mes == mes_actual):
        suma += lista_b[indice]
    else:
        Lista_resultado.append({ultimo_mes: suma})
        suma = 0
        indice -= 1

    # El if y el +1 se encarga de revisar si estamos en el último elemento para guardar la última suma    
    if(indice+1 >= len(lista_a)):
        Lista_resultado.append({mes_actual: suma})    

    indice += 1
    ultimo_mes = mes_actual

print(Lista_resultado) # Resultado: [{'01': 110}, {'02': 150}]
```

El problema es que si yo modifico la *Lista_a* por los siguientes datos `Lista_a = ['10/01/22', '11/01/22', '10/02/22', '11/02/22']` el código ya no funciona. Entonces me gustaría saber qué se puede modificar para solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hacer para resolver el problema?

Comment: Hola, usé los índices negativos pero cuando en la lista_a la cambio por todos los días del año el resultado del primer mes es incongruente y no me aparece el resultado del mes de Diciembre.

Comment: Tu problema es que estas obteniendo el mes seleccionando un rango del String de la fecha. En tu código, tienes fechas en las cuales el día es un solo dígito, y lo estas cambiando por fechas donde el día es de dos dígitos. Por lo que no estas obteniendo el valor correcto. Te recomiendo usar el método `split` de la clase string para obtener el mes correctamente.

Comment: Como dice @Jacobo el split te permite transformar un string dividiendo a traves de un carácter en tu caso seria  .split("/") independientemente de la longitut del dia, mes o año

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dice @Jacobo el split te permite transformar un string dividiendo a traves de un carácter en tu caso seria .split("/") independientemente de la longitut del dia, mes o año.

Solución:

```
#lista_a = ['1/01/22', '2/01/22', '1/02/22', '2/02/22'] #lista antigua
lista_a = ['10/01/22', '11/01/22', '10/02/22', '11/02/22']#lista nueva
lista_b = [50, 60, 70, 80]
Lista_resultado = []

ultimo_mes = lista_a[0].split("/")[1]#obtenemos el mes

suma = 0
indice = 0
while(indice < len(lista_a)):
    mes_actual = lista_a[indice].split("/")[1]#obtenemos el mes

    if(ultimo_mes == mes_actual):
        suma += lista_b[indice]
    else:
        Lista_resultado.append({ultimo_mes: suma})
        suma = 0
        indice -= 1

    # El if y el +1 se encarga de revisar si estamos en el último elemento para guardar la última suma    
    if(indice+1 >= len(lista_a)):
        Lista_resultado.append({mes_actual: suma})    

    indice += 1
    ultimo_mes = mes_actual

print(Lista_resultado) # Resultado: [{'01': 110}, {'02': 150}]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @rexxarcat por el aporte.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo más corto usando un diccionario para acumular los totales:

```
lista_a = ['1/01/22', '2/01/22', '1/02/22', '2/02/22']
lista_b = [50, 60, 70, 80]
totales = {}
for i in range(len(lista_a)):
    _, mes, _ = lista_a[i].split("/")
    totales[mes] = totales.get(mes, 0) + lista_b[i]
print(totales)
```

Simplemente recorres la lista de meses y usas `split()` para separar día, mes y año. Como sólo nos interesa el mes, usamos `_` como variable de descarte.

El truco para sumar días a un mes que no existe en el diccionario `totales` es usar `get(llave, default)` para recuperar el valor anterior.

El método `get()` con default significa que si la llave no existe, se crea e inicializa con el valor dado (cero en nuestro caso).